# SignalR Server How to get return value from client?

Tags: c#, signalr

**server**

```
public void SendToUser(string serverId, string message)
{
    //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("New Msg. Send to {0}, Msg content:{1}", serverId, message));
    var _identity = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(aa => aa.serverId == serverId);
    var aaa = Clients.Client(_identity.connectionId).RcvSendToUser(message);
}
```

**Client**

```
_hub.On("RcvSendToUser", x => Console.WriteLine(x) );
```

My question is:

Server side and Client side are both Console project. 
Can I return value on `_hub.on("RcvSendToUser")` ?  And if yes, how can I get this value at server side?

Comment: SignalR doesn't make it meaningful to return values from the client to the server. The server broadcasts a signal (with possible data) to a varying number of clients. It can be one client, but it can also be two thousand clients. In case of multiple clients, what would the meaning and the mechanism of return values be? Should the server hang there until it receives answers from all clients? Should the server register a callback that is to be called each time a client returns? What happens with dropped connections?

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible to get return values from methods called at the client. One can argument, that a strong-typed hub can be used where the used interface defines some methods that return values.

[link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28874.inside-signalr-addressing-clients-return-values-broken-connections-and-security.aspx)